# Nodejs Process CLI Variable Containing Object

Tags: node.js, argv

I am very new to using the NodeJS CLI command of `process.argv` to be able to pass a variable containing an object to my function method, but it seems that the property values within my object are not being found when this process is called. I am receiving an error at the second property of my object `siteUrl` and can't seem to figure out if it is the way that `process.argv` compiles information or if I am using the command incorrectly. If I replace `process.argv` with `params` then I do not receive errors.

Here is my terminal command:

`node app.js params`

Here is my variable setup:

```
var siteUrl = encodeURIComponent('http://www.test.com/');

    var params = {
        auth: auth,
        siteUrl: siteUrl,
        resource: {
            'startDate': moment().subtract(3, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            'endDate': moment().subtract(2, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            'dimensions': ['query', 'page'],
            'dimensionFilterGroups': [{
              'filters': [{
                'dimension': 'country',
                'operator': 'equals',
                'expression': 'USA'
              }]
            }]
        }
```

Here is my method

```
var query = webmasters.searchanalytics.query(process.argv, function(err, res){
      var formattedQueryList = [];
      if (err){
          console.log('This is the error: ' + err);
      } else { ... }
```

I'm also logging my object to make sure values are present:

```
 console.log(params.resource.startDate)
    console.log(params.resource.startDate)
    console.log(params.resource.endDate)
    console.log(params.siteUrl)
    console.log(siteUrl)
```

here is the console.log:

```
2017-02-11
2017-02-12
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F
This is the error: Error: Missing required parameters: siteUrl
```

Comment: `process.argv` is an array of strings and not an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an argument node treat it as string. So you have to take care of the Json formating. 
e.g. 
You want to pass an object person, here you can explicitly set the **\"**.
`node lib/index.js {\"name\":\"Bob\"}`
Or in a different way with **'** wrapping the json:
`node lib/index.js '{"name":"Bob"}'`

And in your code, you should parse the string as a JSON.

```
const obj =  JSON.parse( process.argv[2] );
console.log(obj);
console.log('Hello ' + obj.name);
```

which will give you `Hello Bob`. In your case you maybe can use `JSON.stringify(params)` before you pass it as argument.
Hope this help to clarify.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and possible solution. I think it may actually be best to use process.argv to populate the individual property values in my object, rather than my current approach

Answer (score 0):

`process.argv` is a list of the parameters you append to the terminal command.

In your case, `process.argv[2]` would be the string `params`, and not the actual variable value. You either need to pass the JSON itself (with proper escaping) via the CLI, then parse it with `JSON.parse`, or manually check the value of `process.argv[2]`.